# How to install ColdFusion server 2021 (Ubuntu 2.0)

Tags: coldfusion, ubuntu-20.04

I just started on ColdFusion and went trough the pain of installing it so check below how it went for me.

Comment: When you refer to this as "the pain of installing it", is it that you preferred or expected something other than what was essentially a single "step" of running the cfinstall.sh (other than unzipping), then answering its few questions? 

FWIW, there is also the full installer. While the docs page you link doesn't mention it, that full installer is offered (as it always has been), which is also just one step to start it (and answer several questions)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Some) instructions for instalation are at

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/user-guide.html/coldfusion/using/install-coldfusion-2021.ug.html

Steps:

1. Download the CFServer for Ubuntu 2.0 (they are not telling you this I had to get it from support)
   https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/track?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:df35d898-6de0-4afe-bccb-03c6afbd0659
2. Run

> unzip ColdFusion_2021_WWEJ_linux64.zip

3. Run

> unzip ColdFusion2021.zip

4. Navigate to where you installed

> cd ColdFusion/cfusion/bin

5. Run the installer

> ./cfinstall.sh

and follow the on-screen instructions.

6. After instalation screens, start ColdFusion

> sudo ./coldfusion start

7. Then, you can access the CF at

> http://127.0.0.1:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm